# How to clear easy digital download (edd) cart before adding to cart? (allow only one item per cart)

Tags: php, wordpress, easy-digital-downloads

How to clear easy digital download (edd) cart before adding to cart? 
allow only one item per cart

Comment: Give us more details to understand what you need.

Answer (score 1):

actually i found the answer before joining stack overflow, but very hard and with many search and try.
now i decide to share it again here to make it easy to find answer for others.

just add code bellow to function.php

```
add_filter( 'edd_pre_add_to_cart_contents', '__return_false' );
```

source: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308362/force-customers-to-add-only-single-item-to-card-per-purchase-edd

Answer (score 0):

Altenative for devolopment;

```html
   /**
 * If there is more than 1 item in the basket and the total price is 0, the basket will be emptied.
 */
function pw_edd_one_item_checkout( $download_id, $options ) {
    if( edd_get_cart_quantity() >= 1 && edd_get_cart_total() == 0) {
        edd_empty_cart();
    }
}
add_action( 'edd_pre_add_to_cart', 'pw_edd_one_item_checkout', 10, 2 );
```